# SQL Server : display column states by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my db schema:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbaea/3

The only important columns are `CreationTime` (as a timestamp) and `Result`.

`Result` can currently be 0, 1, 2 or 3

What my result should look like:

```
Year, Month, Day | Entries with Result 0 | With 1 | With 2 | ..
```

I'm new to SQL Server itself and I have no idea how to solve this problem. I tried some subselects (like in my fiddle) but they are not working as expected. I guess this is because I have to join the subselects, but how? Also I want to know the best way of how to do this..

Some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to union several queries.  You can use a case statement:

```
SELECT
    DAY(CreationTime) AS d, MONTH(CreationTime) AS m, YEAR(CreationTime) AS y
    ,count(CASE WHEN RESULT = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS R0
    ,count(CASE WHEN RESULT = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS R1
    ,count(CASE WHEN RESULT = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS R2
FROM History
GROUP BY DAY(CreationTime), MONTH(CreationTime), YEAR(CreationTime)


SELECT * FROM History;
```

Answer on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc23a/8/0).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT YEAR(CreationTime) AS y, MONTH(CreationTime) AS m, DAY(CreationTime) AS d,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 0 THEN 1 END) AS WITH0,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN 1 END) AS WITH1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 2 THEN 1 END) AS WITH2          
FROM History
GROUP BY YEAR(CreationTime), MONTH(CreationTime), DAY(CreationTime)
```